# SQL Server Count Logins Per Month Per Year with Pivot

Tags: sql-server

I need to count the number of logins per user per month for the whole year, how should I go about this, I think Pivoting might be the answer but can't seem to figure out how to write the query.
I have 2 columns, one with the userID and the other one with the datetime.
if I do `select count(Start) , userID from LoginTable where Start between '2018-01-01' and '2018-12-31' group by userID` I get the number of times the users logged in through the year but how do I separate the results to have the time of logins per month?
Here is the table

[image]

I want to display month in a new column, row month 1 to column Jan, month row 2 to column Feb etc

Like this: 
[image]

Comment: I think you should provide some sample data and expected output.

Comment: @Tab Alleman, sure? show me where

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
declare @LoginTable table (UserId int, [Start] datetime)

insert into @LoginTable (UserId, [Start])
  select 1, '1 jan 2018'
  union all select 2, '1 jan 2018'
  union all select 2, '1 jan 2018'
  union all select 1, '1 feb 2018'
  union all select 2, '1 feb 2018'
  union all select 1, '1 mar 2018'
  union all select 2, '1 mar 2018'
  union all select 1, '1 apr 2018'
  union all select 2, '1 apr 2018'
  union all select 1, '1 may 2018'
  union all select 2, '1 may 2018'
  union all select 1, '1 jun 2018'
  union all select 2, '1 jun 2018'
  union all select 1, '1 jul 2018'
  union all select 2, '1 jul 2018'
  union all select 1, '1 aug 2018'
  union all select 2, '1 aug 2018'
  union all select 1, '1 sep 2018'
  union all select 2, '1 sep 2018'
  union all select 1, '1 oct 2018'
  union all select 2, '1 oct 2018'
  union all select 1, '1 nov 2018'
  union all select 2, '1 nov 2018'
  union all select 1, '1 dec 2018'
  union all select 2, '1 dec 2018'

select UserId, [Year], Y.*
from (
  select UserId, datepart(year,[Start]) [Year], substring(datename(month,[Start]), 1, 3) [Month], count(*) num
  from @LoginTable
  group by UserId, datepart(year,[Start]), substring(datename(month,[Start]), 1, 3)
) X
pivot (
  sum(num)
  for [Month] in ([Jan],[Feb],[Mar],[Apr],[May],[Jun],[Jul],[Aug],[Sep],[Oct],[Nov],[Dec])
) Y
```

PS - Please post your questions like this in future i.e. with sample data and a query attempt that can be copied and pasted out.